# Websocket onmessage event doesnt update component data

Tags: javascript, callback, event-handling, vue.js

I am setting my callbacks in mounted:

```
data() {
    return {
        code: 'Apple',
    }
},
mounted() {
    console.log(this.code) // prints 'Apple'
    this.$options.sockets.onopen = this.wsOpen();
    this.$options.sockets.onmessage = this.logMessage(msg);
},
methods: {
    logMessage(msg){
        this.code += "\n" + msg.data;
        console.log("this.code: " + this.code);
    },
}
```

However it is telling me that 'msg' is not defined.
The following works, however this.code becomes out of scope:

```
this.$options.sockets.onmessage= function (msg) {
        console.log(msg.data) // this works, msg is not undefined here
        console.log(this.code) // doesnt work, this.code is undefined
    }
```

I think im doing something dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set it to the function.

```
this.$options.sockets.onmessage = this.logMessage;
```

The code is currently setting `onmessage` to the *result* of `this.logMessage(msg)`, and as the error states, `msg` is not defined `mounted`.